# Visible sequence of side effects

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, language-lawyer

I was confused by the definition of the **visible sequence of side effects** concept defined at `5.1.2.4(p22)`:

> The visible sequence of side effects on an atomic object `M`, with
>   respect to a value computation `B` of `M`, is a maximal contiguous
>   sub-sequence of side effects in the modification order of `M`, where the
>   first side effect is visible with respect to `B`, and for every
>   subsequent side effect, it is not the case that `B` happens before it.

Here is my current understanding of the concept:

Since the visible side effect with respect to B should be the "closest one happens before `B`" side effect I can imagine the following case:

```
_Atomic int i = 10;

void *increment(void *ignored){
    i++;
    printf("%d\n", i); //<<----- B
}

void *decrement(void *ignored){
    i--;
    printf("%d\n", i);
}

int main(void){
   i = 100;
   //start two threads with increment and decrement correspondingly
}
```

Considering the case above I assumed that `B` is the value computation in the `increment` function so the visible sequence of side effects with respect to `B` is "`i++`, `i--`". Since `i = 100` is sequenced before creation of the threads it does not belong to visible sequence of side effects with respect to `B`.

Does my interpretation mean what it really is?

Comment: You make a confusion between C and C++. C++ is not C.

The comitee cut this concept out of the standard as it was redundant.

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_406.htm

Comment: @alinsoar _You make a confusion between C and C++_ I don't really understand what you mean by that. I did not even read what's C++ specifies about it. Also why did you delete the C tag? I quoted N1570 draft. I rolled it back.

Comment: mea culpa.  I thought it was quoted from C++ .  But you find the answer in technical corrigendum I posted.

Comment: I think you are making an incorrect assumption here that if you start 2 threads in sequence "A" and then "B", then thread "A" will run before thread "B".

They will _probably_ execute in that order but it is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

The [working draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf) of the C2x standard incorporates the changes that were made in the C17 ("bugfix") standard. The primary purpose of the changes to this section are to align the memory coherence models between C++ and C, and remove the redundancy as noted in the [DR406](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_406.htm) Defect Report.

As you can see, the committee has gone to great pains to try and clarify the memory coherence model and simplify what constitutes a "data race".

The tricky part is that only one of the changes in the C17 bugfix is "normative", meaning that conforming implementations won't have to consider the changes to this section until the C2x standard is finalized.

As far as your interpretation of the *existing* section of the current standard, I'd have to say it's a moot point. The standards committee acknowledges the confusion and ambiguity in the current version, and you would probably be better served to wait until this section has a chance to settle down under the new C2x standard before worrying too much about it.

> **16** An evaluation A *inter-thread happens before* an evaluation B if A synchronizes with B, A is
>    dependency-ordered before B, or, for some evaluation X:
>
> - A synchronizes with X and X is sequenced before B,
> - A is sequenced before X and X inter-thread happens before B, or
> - A inter-thread happens before X and X inter-thread happens before B.
>
>   ---
>
>   15)The "carries a dependency" relation is a subset of the "sequenced before" relation, and is similarly strictly intra-thread.
>     16)The "dependency-ordered before" relation is analogous to the "synchronizes with" relation, but uses release/consume in
>     place of release/acquire.
>
> **17** NOTE 7 The "inter-thread happens before" relation describes arbitrary concatenations of "sequenced before", "synchronizes
>   with", and "dependency-ordered before" relationships, with two exceptions. The first exception is that a concatenation is
>   not permitted to end with "dependency-ordered before" followed by "sequenced before". The reason for this limitation is
>   that a consume operation participating in a "dependency-ordered before" relationship provides ordering only with respect
>   to operations to which this consume operation actually carries a dependency. The reason that this limitation applies only
>   to the end of such a concatenation is that any subsequent release operation will provide the required ordering for a prior
>   consume operation. The second exception is that a concatenation is not permitted to consist entirely of "sequenced before".
>   The reasons for this limitation are (1) to permit "inter-thread happens before" to be transitively closed and (2) the "happens
>   before" relation, defined below, provides for relationships consisting entirely of "sequenced before".
>
> **18** An evaluation A *happens before* an evaluation B if A is sequenced before B or A inter-thread happens
>   before B. The implementation shall ensure that no program execution demonstrates a cycle in the
>   "happens before" relation.
>
> **19** NOTE 8 This cycle would otherwise be possible only through the use of consume operations.
>
> **20** A visible side effect A on an object M with respect to a value computation B of M satisfies the
>   conditions:
>
> - A happens before B, and
> - there is no other side effect X to M such that A happens before X and X happens before B.
>     The value of a non-atomic scalar object M, as determined by evaluation B, shall be the value stored
>     by the visible side effect A.
>
> **21** NOTE 9 If there is ambiguity about which side effect to a non-atomic object is visible, then there is a data race and the
>   behavior is undefined.
>
> **22** NOTE 10 This states that operations on ordinary variables are not visibly reordered. This is not actually detectable without
>   data races, but it is necessary to ensure that data races, as defined here, and with suitable restrictions on the use of atomics,
>   correspond to data races in a simple interleaved (sequentially consistent) execution.
>
> **23** The value of an atomic object M, as determined by evaluation B, shall be the value stored by some
>   side effect A that modifies M, where B does not happen before A.
>
> **24** NOTE 11 The set of side effects from which a given evaluation might take its value is also restricted by the rest of the rules
>   described here, and in particular, by the coherence requirements below.
>
> **25** If an operation A that modifies an atomic object M happens before an operation B that modifies M,
>   then A shall be earlier than B in the modification order of M.
>
> **26** NOTE 12 The requirement above is known as "write-write coherence".
>
> **27** If a value computation A of an atomic object M happens before a value computation B of M, and A
>   takes its value from a side effect X on M, then the value computed by B shall either be the value
>   stored by X or the value stored by a side effect Y on M, where Y follows X in the modification
>   order of M.
>
> **28** NOTE 13 The requirement above is known as "read-read coherence".
>
> **29** If a value computation A of an atomic object M happens before an operation B on M, then A shall
>   take its value from a side effect X on M, where X precedes B in the modification order of M.
>
> **30** NOTE 14 The requirement above is known as "read-write coherence".
>
> **31** If a side effect X on an atomic object M happens before a value computation B of M, then the
>   evaluation B shall take its value from X or from a side effect Y that follows X in the modification
>   order of M.
>
> **32** NOTE 15 The requirement above is known as "write-read coherence".
>
> **33** NOTE 16 This effectively disallows compiler reordering of atomic operations to a single object, even if both operations are
>   "relaxed" loads. By doing so, it effectively makes the "cache coherence" guarantee provided by most hardware available to C
>   atomic operations.
>
> **34** NOTE 17 The value observed by a load of an atomic object depends on the "happens before" relation, which in turn depends
>   on the values observed by loads of atomic objects. The intended reading is that there exists an association of atomic loads
>   with modifications they observe that, together with suitably chosen modification orders and the "happens before" relation
>   derived as described above, satisfy the resulting constraints as imposed here.